# wrap two divs in a container

Tags: jquery, html

I have a container which contains multiple divs, of which i need to wrap two of them in another div, using jquery. Please suggest the possible way.

actual structure

```
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='a'>abcd</div>
 <div class='b'>abcd</div>
 <div class='c'>abcd</div>
 <div class='d'>abcd</div>
</div>
```

expected structure:

```
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='a'>abcd</div>
 <div class='child'>
  <div class='b'>abcd</div>
  <div class='c'>abcd</div>
 </div>
 <div class='d'>abcd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `wrapAll()` function! It wraps all the elements that match the selector! :)

`$('.b,.c').wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>');`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F7uQV/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Use [wrapAll method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/):

```
$('.b, .c').wrapAll('<div class="child" />');
```

[inspect this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vq3e/)

Answer (score 2):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgEm5/2/)**

```
$('.b,.c').wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>')
```

use Jquery **[.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)** - It wraps the html structure around all the matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
.wrap(): Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.
.wrapAll(): Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.
```

.wrap() wraps every element individually, but .wrapAll() wraps all of them as a group.

For example:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

With $('.foo').wrap('');, this happens:

```
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
```

But with $('.foo').wrapAll('');, this happens:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Atlast you can use WrapAll function to do so :-)

Answer (score -1):

Below is a way to call your jQuery after Wrap element

```
<div class='form-container'>
    ...
    <div class='form-label'>Name (required)</div>
    <div class='form-field'><input type="text" name="you-name" value="" class="textbox" size="30" maxlength="200" /></div>

    <div class='form-label'>Email (required)</div>
    <div class='form-field'><input type="text" name="you-email" value="" class="textbox" size="30" maxlength="200" /></div>
    ...
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(".form-container .form-label").each(function(index) {
        $(this).next(".form-field").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='form-element-wrapper' />")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This answer won't specifically solve what OP wanted. It will match every .form-label under .form-container, whereas OP only wanted a couple of divs to be matched.